# How to set DateTime object to null and sent as parameter to stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures

I call stored procedure from my visual studio project and passing DateTime parameter.

Here is c# code:

```
DateTime? dtStartFrom = null;
var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DamageEventsDTL>("SPDamageEventsDTL  @dtStartFrom", new SqlParameter("dtStartFrom", dtStartFrom)).ToList();
```

Here how variable defined in stored procedure:

```
@dtStartFrom date
```

on this row I get this exception:

```
The parameterized query '(@dtStartFrom nvarchar(4000))SPDamageEventsDTL  @dtStartFrom' expects the parameter '@dtStartFrom', which was not supplied.
```

So I guess there is problem with null values, so I tryed this way:

```
 DateTime? dtStartFrom = DBNull.Value;
```

But on row above I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'System.DateTime?'
```

Any idea how can I set DateTime object to null and sent as parameter to my stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried naming the sqlparameter @dtStartFrom instead of just dtStartFrom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter name should match that of the query:

```
new SqlParameter("@dtStartFrom", dtStartFrom);
```

Edit:

```
DateTime? dtStartFrom = null;
SqlParameter sqlDateparam = new SqlParameter("@dtStartFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlDateparam.IsNullable = true;

if (dtStartFrom.HasValue)
    sqlDateparam.Value = dtStartFrom.Value;
else
    sqlDateparam.Value = DBNull.Value

var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DamageEventsDTL>("SPDamageEventsDTL  @dtStartFrom", sqlDateparam).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but now I get error:

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Is it possible to sent null as parameter?

Comment: Re: _"SqlDateTime overflow"_, are you using type `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` in the DB?

Comment: @Michael: That type is limited to dates in the reported range. **1.** Could it be that you're trying to store a date value outside the range? Consider switching to `DATETIME2` in your DB schema. (This is what Microsoft recommends, too.) **2.** is the DB field actually nullable, or does it have a `NOT NULL` constraint?

Comment: It is defined as nullable

Comment: I try to convert dateTime to SqlDateTime and I get this error :

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Comment: @Michael Why are you converting ? You said you just want to pass *NULL*